# Rails validation for collection select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the below form which is used for creation of a new Order:

```
<label>Client Name*</label>
<%= f.collection_select :client_id, current_user.clients, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select Client"},{ class: "form-control"} %>
<br/>
<label>Service Name</label>
<%= f.collection_select :service_id, current_user.services, :id, :name ,{prompt: "Select Service"},{ class: "form-control"} %>
<label>Service Fee</label>
<%= f.text_field :amount, min: 0,max: 99, placeholder: "Enter the service fee",class: "form-control" %> <br/>
<label>Service Start Date</label><br/>
<%= f.date_select :from_date, placeholder: "Enter the service start date",class: "form-control" %> <br/>
<label>Service End Date</label> <br/>
<%= f.date_select :to_date, placeholder: "Enter the service end date",class: "form-control" %> <br/>
<br/>
```

The Order Model has the validations shown below which ensures that Client id and Service id are mandatory. However if the client Name is left blank and only the Service Name is selected, the below error message is displayed:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass on the below line

@order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}"

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user
validates_presence_of :client_id, :service_id ,:amount, :from_date, :to_date, :order_title => "Should be present"
validates_uniqueness_of :client_id, scope: :service_id, scope: :user_id, :message => " Serive combination already exists" 
validates_numericality_of :amount 
validates_date :to_date, :after =>  :from_date, :before_message => "Service End Date should be greater than #{:from_date}"
end
```

If the user leaves the field blank, the same should be flagged as an error message.Same is the case if Service Name is left blank. How can this be resolved? Please help. Below is the create method

```
def create
@order = Order.new(order_params)
client = Client.find_by_id(@order.client_id)
service = Service.find_by_id(@order.service_id)

@order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}"
@order.user_id = current_user.id
if @order.save
redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Successfully created Order!"
else
  render action: 'new'
end
end
```

Comment: In `Client` model check `validates_presence_of :name`

Comment: yes Client model has this validation. The User has to fill in this field mandatory while creation of a new Client.

Comment: what is your `rails` version

Comment: Rails 4.1.0 im using Nitrous.io

Comment: TRy using `validates :name, :presence => true`

Comment: no luck same error. I think I figured out the error. The validations are checked for only when the create method is called by rails. Here the @order.save method comes after the line order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}" and when a blank value is selected, the error is thrown, I need to figure out a way to check if the user has left the field blank before the create method in the controller is called

Comment: No, validations are checked whenever `create
create!
save
save!
update
update!` this methods are called. If you want to keep validation you have to explicitly specify that `@order.save(validate: false)`

Comment: Could you please post the controller the form above is handled by? (Probably an OrdersController)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: You're fighting ActiveRecord by relying on attributes of an `Order` before it's validated. Move the line `@order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}` to a `title` method on `Order` (or set `order_title` in an `after_create` callback), so the form validation can do its thing.

Or, if you must keep this code in the controller, you can set the title after validation:

```
def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    client = Client.find_by_id(@order.client_id)
    service = Service.find_by_id(@order.service_id)    


    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    if @order.valid?
        @order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}"
        @order.save
        redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Successfully created Order!"
    else
        render action: 'new'
    end
end
```

---

Use `validates_presence_of :client` instead of `:client_id`:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :client
    has_many :payments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user
    validates_presence_of :client, :service_id ,:amount, :from_date, :to_date, :order_title => "Should be present"
    validates_uniqueness_of :client_id, scope: :service_id, scope: :user_id, :message => " Serive combination already exists" 
    validates_numericality_of :amount 
    validates_date :to_date, :after =>  :from_date, :before_message => "Service End Date should be greater than #{:from_date}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating new `client`, you already have `@order` member variable created, and you are just populating fields in it - so, you need to set the client for `@order` more correct is to  use `@order.client.name` instead.

As @thebenedict said you can use

Use validates_presence_of :client instead of :client_id:

`validates_presence_of :client, :service`

**EDIT**:Try this. When you are selecting client and service from select boxes in the form `client_id` and `service_id` are sent. So check you `params`

```
def create
     @order = Order.new(order_params)
     client = Client.find_by_id(params[:client_id])
     service = Service.find_by_id(params[:service_id])
     @order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}"
     @order.user_id = current_user.id
     if @order.save
        redirect_to orders_path, notice: "Successfully created Order!"
     else
        render action: 'new'
     end
end
```

Comment: Sorry either im confused or got you guys confused. The line which throws the error is this  order.order_title = "#{client.name}_#{service.name}" the @order.save method comes after the above line. Hence when the user submits the form with the field blank, nill.name is called resulting in the error I believe.

Comment: Can you show us that method, where you are writing this, to kill the confusion